# Replace a xml attribute value without cut it is original xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to replace the xml attribute value that being retrieved from database, and after replace, I want to get original xml with the changed attribute value.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseRepository repository = ....

        var xml = ExtractXML(repository.MyXML);

        repository.MyXML = xml;
    }

private XElement ExtractXML(string oriXML)
    {
        try
        {
            var xml = XElement.Parse(oriXML);

            if (xml != null)
            {
                var extract = xml.Descendants("fields");

                foreach (XElement xElement in extract)
                {
                    // The error occurs from below
                    if (xElement.Attribute("name").Value.ToLower().Equals("from") && xElement.Attribute("column").Value.ToLower().Equals("fromplayerdate"))
                    {
                        xElement.Attribute("value").Value = "From";
                    }

                    if (xElement.Attribute("name").Value.ToLower().Equals("to") && xElement.Attribute("column").Value.ToLower().Equals("toplayerdate"))
                    {
                        xElement.Attribute("value").Value = "To";
                    }
                }

                xml.Save(oriXML);
            }

            return xml;
        }

        catch (XmlException ex)
        {
            LOGGER.Error(string.Format("ExtractXML(). Exception: {0}", ex.Message));

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is my XML:

> ```
> <fields>
>   <field name="From" column="FromPlayerDate" value="Player"></field>
>   <field name="To" column="ToPlayerDate" value="Player"></field>
> </fields>
> ```

I want it after the value has been changed, it will be like this the ***repository.MyXML***:

> ```
> <fields>
>   <field name="From" column="FromPlayerDate" value="From"></field>
>   <field name="To" column="ToPlayerDate" value="To"></field>
> </fields>
> ```

I got the following error in the first if after foreach statement:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to manipulate `xml.Descendants("field")` and not `xml.Descendants("fields")`.

Comment: Thank you @Martin Honnen. Solved :)

Comment: Well, `xml.Save()` is meant to save the XML tree to a file (with the file name passed as an argument), as you load from a string I suppose you want to store `xml.ToString()` to your repository.

Comment: note also that in xml you say `column="ToPlayerDateDate"` (duplicate Date?) but in code you check `...Equals("toplayerdate")`.

Comment: Hi @S.Serp, it supposed to be single `Date`, my mistake to not notice that while copy-paste into here. Thanks for pointed that out :)